# how could resolved "CDISP0092E ERROR: Because of previous compilation errors, the compile process cannot continue."?

Tags: vmware-player, ibm-streams

I want to create a project in the Project explorer of the Streams studio (vmware workstation player.I have entered the project name and then I have created the "Filesink", "Filesource" and "Filter" in my project name, but when I save, I get this error message:
"CDISP0092E ERROR: Because of previous compilation errors, the compile process cannot continue."how could resolved ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per default auto-build is enabled in Streams Studio. When you save your project
the project build is triggered.
You could disable this in the menu Project-> Build Automatically (unset), for example to avoid error messages during your application creation and you know that you are not ready.

Otherwise to learn more about the error, scroll up in the Console, and check the error messages prior CDISP0092E.

Most likely they are similar to the messages below:

```
application/Test.spl:6:11: CDISP0053E ERROR: An unknown identifier was referenced in the SPL program: varType.
application/Test.spl:17:11: CDISP0053E ERROR: An unknown identifier was referenced in the SPL program: varType.
application/Test.spl:14:12: CDISP0053E ERROR: An unknown identifier was referenced in the SPL program: parameterValue.
```

It might be that mandatory operator parameters are not set and/or the Stream schemas are not defined.
To configure those properties, double-click on the operators and/or connected stream(s).